# Getting 404 errors on getting resources after deploying Flutter Web project into Azure Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I got this error 404 which is not loading my resources and assets from my created `flutter` web application after deploying into Azure web app.

See the example photo:
[image: Browser console log]

I use `FTP` method to upload files and used `FileZilla` as my tool. I upload all the files include in this generated files after running "flutter build web"

```
build/web/all_my_files
```

I already configured properly my `pubspec.yaml` file.

Note: This works all fine on `GitHub` pages but after I tried to deploy on azure this happens and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `web.config` should be configured with the other external static files like `.json`. It should be deployed beside the Flutter `index.html` file.

The `web.config` should be like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="utf-8" ?>
  
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <!-- JSON Manifests -->
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
            <!-- Fonts -->
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttc" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks sir, can I copy this one? Do I need to add or edit? Is this fine already?

Comment: Yes... you can copy it. No problem. You can edit it to add any other resource that gets 404 again but it's fine the way it is already.